# What is the difference between "python" and "pythonw" in the mac Terminal?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, terminal

im fairly new to programming in Python and i've been using the terminal to run my code with no problem. Usually by typing python {filename} to run it.

However, recently i got this error:

ImportError: Python is not installed as a framework. The Mac OS X backend will not be able to function correctly if Python is not installed as a framework. See the Python documentation for more information on installing Python as a framework on Mac OS X. Please either reinstall Python as a framework, or try one of the other backends. If you are using (Ana)Conda please install python.app and replace the use of 'python' with 'pythonw'. See 'Working with Matplotlib on OSX' in the Matplotlib FAQ for more information.

then i changed the python {filename} to pythonw {filename} and the code worked. Could someone give me some insight into this error and why it worked by just adding w?

Comment: Have a look at the man-page. In Terminal type `man pythonw`.

Answer (score 1):

pythonw - run python script allowing GUI.  According to the man page for pythonw.

Comment: Also in that man page: _"Actually, since Python 2.5, the normal python also allows GUI access, so python and pythonw are now interchangeable."_ So I don't know why it was not working for OP, unless he was using a very old version of Python...